# Fail the test if an asset fails to load

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I have a Nightwatch test that looks as follows:

```
browser
  .url(MY_URL)
  .assert.visible(MY_SELECTOR)
```

The test fails due to element not being present on the page:

```
Testing if element <.my_selector> is visible in 5000ms - expected "is visible" but got: "element could not be located" (5170ms)
```

The element has not been rendered because a script that does so failed to load. Is there a way to make the test fail early citing missing script?

Comment: It might not be exactly what you're after, but the `.url()` command takes a callback as its second parameter. Maybe you can handle something on this callback? https://nightwatchjs.org/api/commands/#url